# Merge develop and master branches

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I am newbie in git (github). 
I have just one simple question.
There are two branches on github. One is master branch, that contains old code, and the other one is develop branch, that contains the latest code. How I can merge these branches, so that the master branch will contain the latest code I have written on develop branch. Thanks much in advance.

Comment: What did you try to do?

Answer (score 0):

*git merge* will help you:

```
git clone https://github.com/youraccount/yourproject.git
git checkout --tract origin/develop
git checkout master
git merge develop
git push
```